# Can we use 'as' in SQL Server as a variable

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT  
    LineId, [LineNumber],
    ROUND(SUM(Quantity), 3) AS TotalNeed,
    SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineId(LineId) AS TotalMRC,
    SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineId(LineId) AS TotalMIV,
    SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineId(LineId) AS TotalIMIV,
    (TotalMRC-TotalMIV ) AS Shortage
FROM 
    [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO]
GROUP BY 
    lineid, [LineNumber]
```

but I get these errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LineMaterialStatus, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'TotalMRC'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LineMaterialStatus, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'TotalMIV'.

My question is can we use 'as' as a variable to hold value in SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a subquery to achieve this:

```
SELECT  LineId,
        [LineNumber],
        TotalNeed,
        TotalMRC,
        TotalMIV,
        TotalIMIV,
        (TotalMRC - TotalMIV) as Shortage
  FROM  (
        SELECT  LineId,[LineNumber],
                round(sum(Quantity),3) as TotalNeed
                ,SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineId(LineId) as TotalMRC
                ,SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineId(LineId) as TotalMIV
                ,SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineId(LineId)  as TotalIMIV
          FROM  [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO]
          GROUP BY lineid,[LineNumber]
        ) a
```

You can select the output from the first statement as the source subquery for the second one, which lets you use the calculated columns that you created.

You then simply move `(TotalMRC - TotalMIV) as Shortage` to the outer query which then has the calculated columns available.

Answer (score 4):

The normal solution to this question is to use CTEs or subqueries.

I like to point out that SQL Server has an alternative method, `outer apply`:

```
  SELECT mto.LineId, mto.[LineNumber], round(sum(mto.Quantity), 3) as TotalNeed
         v.*, (v.TotalMRC - v.TotalMIV ) as Shortage
  FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO] mto OUTER APPLY
       (VALUES (SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineId(mto.LineId),
                SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineId(mto.LineId),
                SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineId(mto.LineId)
               )
       ) v(TotalMRC, TotalMIV, TotalIMIV)
  GROUP BY mto.lineid, mto.[LineNumber];
```

Comment: So which one is faster your solution or @parkin solution ?

Comment: No need to `OUTER` this. `CROSS` will work fine as the apply is guaranteed to return 1 row per row in mto.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar RE: which is faster, if you are trying to optimise this then ditching the scalar UDFs will likely be the best thing.